# ASP.NET Page-Scroll Following Div

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I would like to implement a site wide alarm/notification system as in stackoverflow, where there is a horizontal div telling you when there is somebody answering your question ( the one on the top, yellow background notification ). The problem is, is there anything like that in the .NET control?

How could I achieve so? I succeeded building one, but it is a simple div, without following page scroll. I want a notification that follows page scroll so that it captures user attention.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For the notification bar itself you can use a jQuery plugin called jbar: http://tympanus.net/codrops/2009/10/29/jbar-a-jquery-notification-plugin/

The other piece is you are going to have to use Comet to know when something has happened server side in the client. For that I reccomend using Long Polling with SignalR:

NuGet: http://nuget.org/List/Packages/SignalR

Github: https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR

Comment: I wil give it a try. Just quick questions tho, will this require additional library during the deployment?

Comment: jBar will require jQuery and SIgnalR you will need jquery.signalR.min.js and a couple SignalR assemblies.